# 404 error when Accessing from local host : NGINX uWSGI

Tags: django, nginx, docker, uwsgi

I am trying to configure a docker compose example with nginx (running in a container) fronting 3 containers running a python app in uwsgi.

when trying nginx through docker ip for the container, the app is accessible without any issue; however, when trying to access it from the host url (nginx is bound to host using port 9999) using localhost:9999 I can access the nginx page, however any app urls or /admin/ uri are showing up with a 404 error.

I have gone through tons of forums and Stackoverflow answers without any luck, could someone please help me resolve this ?

More information attached below:

my docker compose file looks like below:

```
version:  '2'
services:
  nginxlb:
    build:  ./nginx
    ports:
      - "9999:80"
    links:
      - my-app1:my-app1
      - my-app2:my-app2
      - my-app3:my-app3
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx/:/opt/my-logs/nginx/
  my-app1:
    build: ./my
    expose:
      - 8080
      - 8081
    volumes:
      - ./logs/node1:/opt/my-logs/node1/
  my-app2:
    build: ./my
    volumes:
      - ./logs/node2/:/opt/my-logs/node2/
    expose:
      - 8080
      - 8081
  my-app3:
    build: ./my
    volumes:
      - ./logs/node3:/opt/my-logs/node3
    expose:
      - 8080
      - 8081
```

site-enabled conf for nginx looks like the following:

```
upstream node-app {
      least_conn;
      server my-app1:8080;
      server my-app2:8080;
      server my-app3:8080;
}

server {
      listen 80 default;
      server_name _;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://node-app;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
      }
}
```

**EDIT** this is my Docker file for NGINX I have not made any changes for the default nginx.conf file

```
From nginx

MAINTAINER  DevOps

# Update the container
RUN apt-get update

# Create directories and set working directory
RUN mkdir /opt/myapp/
RUN mkdir /opt/myapp/django-static/
RUN mkdir /opt/myapp/django-media/
RUN mkdir /opt/myapp/webroot/
run mkdir -p /opt/myapp-logs/nginx/
WORKDIR /opt/myapp/

# Copy configs and code to Container
ADD config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD config/nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf
ADD config/uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: 404 suggests nginx doesn't reach your `server` nginx config block; maybe parameters in default nginx config file override your config? Did you try to delete it? If that doesn't help please post contents of your nginx/Dockerfile.

Comment: the nginx server serves the uwsgi content when accessed through the nginx container ip (obtained through 'sudo docker inspect <containerid> | grep IPAddress'.

Comment: just added my nginx Dockerfile, I am thinking whether I am doing the docker networking right with the compose file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx config file for the default site includes line:

```
    server_name  localhost;
```

so this config is used when you go to `http://localhost:9999`; additionally - nginx does not process the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory and its content; from the default `nginx.conf`:

```
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Modify your Dockerfile - instead of:

```
ADD config/nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf
```

use:

```
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD config/nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
```